# Can natural weapons be used for unarmed strikes?

Tags: dnd-5e, unarmed-combat, natural-weapon

While there are several similar questions they all seem to deal with 3.5 or Pathfinder. [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50654/is-a-wild-shape-attack-considered-an-unarmed-strike) may contain the key to the answer for this, but focuses on Wildshape, doesn't have an accepted answer despite being 4 years old, and only establishes that natural weapons aren't automatically unarmed strikes (not whether they can be used for said strikes) - a semantic detail that seems important here. I've been struggling to find an official position on this for 5e.

An [answer to a related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/146860/43956) asserts that only some examples of natural weapons can be used for unarmed strikes, giving this example from the [Cat's Claws trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tabaxi#TabaxiTraits) (VGtM, p. 115), which says:

> [...] your claws are natural weapons, *which you can use to make unarmed strikes*...

This, however, seems ambiguous to me - is it saying that this specific example creates an exception where *these* natural weapons can be used for unarmed strikes? If so, the comma seems unnecessary and potentially misleading. A clearer way of putting it might be 'your claws are natural weapons *and* can be used to make unarmed strikes.' If it was intended the other way, though, it could be clearer to say 'your claws are natural weapons, and can *therefore* be used to make unarmed strikes.'

Of course, neither of these wordings are used, hence the confusion. Is there an official position on whether natural weapons (which I understand as being a part of the attacking creature's body) can be used for unarmed attacks (which I recall reading are somewhat defined as being made with body parts, certainly that's how it sounds in [this JC tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/951895470967672832?lang=en)) by default<sup>1</sup>, or whether a *specific* exception must be made?

<sup>1. Also implied by the [unarmed-combat](/questions/tagged/unarmed-combat) descriptive text, not that that's 5e specific though.</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No, except where a trait or feature explicitly allows it.

[The question you linked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/146855/33569) addresses the definition of a natural weapon: they are "natural" body parts that function as weapons. As [Rubiksmoose's answer to that question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/146860/33569) cites, they are described in the intro to the *Monster Manual* (p. 10-11) or [the corresponding portion of the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#MeleeandRangedAttacks):

> The most common actions that a monster will take in combat are melee and ranged attacks. These can be spell attacks or weapon attack, where the "weapon" might be a manufactured item or **a natural weapon such as a claw or tail spike**.

Unarmed strikes are more readily defined in a player-facing document, the PHB or basic rules, specifically the section of the combat rules on [melee combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks):

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an **unarmed strike**: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons). On a hit, an unarmed strike deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your Strength modifier. You are proficient with your unarmed strikes.

As you can see, unarmed strikes are definitively not weapons.

However, natural weapons *are* considered weapons (though a separate category from simple and martial weapons), as reiterated later in the answer - though [the designers did not *always* consider natural weapons when designing every game feature that references a "weapon"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/151319/33569) (so some elements of the game were designed with the intent of working with natural weapons, while others were not).

Based on these definitions, we can begin to assess whether there is overlap between natural weapons and unarmed strikes. Natural weapons seem to be defined in a way that those body parts that are natural weapons clearly function as weapons, whereas the examples given for unarmed strikes generally indicate the use of a mundane body part whose default/sole function is not as a weapon.

#### In the rules

The rulebooks don't seem to explicitly refute the possibility of natural weapons being used for unarmed strikes - but the rules also don't state as a general rule that natural weapons *can* be used for unarmed strikes.

For almost every playable race that does have natural weapons, it is explicitly stated that they can be used for unarmed strikes, suggesting that this is an exception to the general rule; otherwise it'd be very redundant.

For instance, [lizardfolk have the Bite trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/lizardfolk#LizardfolkTraits) (VGtM, p. 113):

> **Your fanged maw is a natural weapon, which you can use to make unarmed strikes.** If you hit with it, you deal piercing damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier, instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike.

[Tabaxi have the Cat's Claws trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tabaxi#TabaxiTraits) (VGtM, p. 115):

> Because of your claws, you have a climbing speed of 20 feet. In addition, **your claws are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes.** If you hit with them, you deal slashing damage equal to 1d4 + your Strength modifier, instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike.

[Centaurs have the Hooves trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/centaur#CentaurTraits) (GGtR, p. 16):

> **Your hooves are natural melee weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes.** If you hit with them, you deal bludgeoning damage equal to 1d4 + your Strength modifier, instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike.

[Minotaurs have the Horns trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/minotaur#MinotaurTraits) (GGtR, p. 19):

> **Your horns are natural melee weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes.** If you hit with them, you deal piercing damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier, instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike.

And at 5th level, [Simic Hybrids have the Grappling Appendages option for their Animal Enhancement trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/simic-hybrid#SimicHybridTraits) (GGTR, p. 20):

> You have two special appendages growing alongside your arms. Choose whether they’re both claws or tentacles. As an action, you can use one of them to try to grapple a creature. **Each one is also a natural weapon, which you can use to make an unarmed strike.** [...]

As you can see, almost every single time that a playable race has a natural weapon, the rules clearly state that they can be used for unarmed strikes. If there were a general rule that natural weapons could be used for unarmed strikes, this would be a *lot* of needless repetition.

The fact that it is repeated in this way every single time strongly indicates that the general rule is that natural weapons aren't used to make unarmed strikes, and that these racial traits define an exception to that rule. It's not proof, but it is a strong argument in favor of this interpretation.

---

The one exception to this trend is the [dhampir lineage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/lineages#Dhampir) from *Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft*. The description of the [dhampir's Vampiric Bite trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vrgtr/character-creation#DhampirTraits) says, in part (emphasis mine):

> **Your fanged bite is a natural weapon, which counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient.** You add your Constitution modifier, instead of your Strength modifier, to the attack and damage rolls when you attack with this bite. It deals 1d4 piercing damage on a hit. [...]

Here, the Vampiric Bite trait specifies that the bite natural weapon is considered a simple melee weapon, rather than being used to make unarmed strikes. Since the trait does not state that the bite can be used to make unarmed strikes, it can not. This sets it apart from all other playable races so far, and further reinforces that being a natural weapon doesn't automatically imply the ability to make unarmed strikes with them.

---

#### Official ruling in the Sage Advice Compendium

As of October 2020, the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=13) explicitly distinguishes natural weapons from unarmed strikes as part of its answer to a related question:

> **Are natural weapons considered weapons?**
>
> Things designated as weapons by the rules, including natural weapons,
> are indeed weapons. In contrast, unarmed strikes are not weapons. They
> are something you do with an unarmed part of your body.

As you can see, the SAC clearly indicates that natural weapons are weapons, and that unarmed strikes are not. This makes it clear that natural weapons and unarmed strikes are different things by default.

As noted above, a number of playable races' racial traits do explicitly make an exception to this, allowing those specific natural weapons to make unarmed strikes (even though natural weapons can't normally be used for unarmed strikes in general).

#### Unofficial rulings on Twitter

*Unofficially*, rules designer Jeremy Crawford has clearly stated many times on Twitter that natural weapons aren't used for unarmed strikes by default (e.g. in [this pair of tweets in July 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/756549963446837249), and [this one in January 2018](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/955566965619240960), and [this one from the following month](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/968383119064731648)).

He has consistently stated that attacks with natural weapons are not unarmed strikes, except where the rules clearly state an exception. This unofficial ruling is consistent with the rules references above, as well as with the official ruling in the Sage Advice Compendium.

Comment: The fact that *every* playable race that has access to natural weapons has the phrase 'natural (...) weapon(s), which you can use to make unarmed strikes' could equally imply that they are natural weapons, and natural weapons can be used to make unarmed strikes - especially as there doesn't seem to be any exceptions (at least from the point of view of a playable character).

Though if JC says they're *not* compatible with unarmed strikes by default, perhaps it's just suboptimal phrasing. I mean, with the sheer volume of material in the books it can't all be crystal straight away.

Comment: Giving it some time has brought me around. This definitely seems the most logical ruling to me, and to be most in line with JC's existing rulings.

Answer (score 1):

Since tabaxi can use their claws as unarmed strikes per the RAW, I would have to rule that a Tabaxi monk could use them as unarmed strikes for slashing damage or the higher of whatever their regular monk damage would be (inculding enlarging the tabaxi for a larger weapon and more damage).

Following this course of logic and the numerously stated fact that ver significantly similar weapons are just re-skins of each other, I would have to rule that the charactar's proficiency bonus plus the beast forms relevant ability score (STR or DES) would be the correct attack bonus for the wild shaped multi-classed characters attack with claws (only claws, not trample for mammoth form, nor bite for bear, nor Anything but beastly claws). The same would be true for bites from a lizardfolk in wild shape, or hooves from a centaur in wild shape, or horns from a Minotaur similarly changed.

While D&D isn't a physics-accurate simulation game, I don't find a RAW listing that negates this train of logic. If I've overlooked something, please let me know.

Comment: If you check out WoTC's web site, they have a sage advice compendium that I think addresses this. You may want to use that to support your answer. Welcome to RPGSE.  Tour, Help, Ask, and Answer provide guidance on how to best use this SE formatted site.  (PS: how you ruled it is how I run it in my game with a tabaxi monk. )

Comment: I'm confused as to the claim this answer is making about the general case - that is, whether natural weapons can be used for unarmed strikes in all other cases where it *doesn't* explicitly say "Your [X]es are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes." All your examples are situations where the natural weapon is from a PC's racial trait that *does* explicitly say it can be used for unarmed strikes.

Answer (score -2):

## Generally no, but there are exeptions

If *all* natural weapons could be used as unarmed strikes, a Druid 18/Monk 2 could do 25 damage<sup>1</sup> with +10 to hit as a *bonus action*. Twice per short rest, it can be 2 attacks per bonus action.

If these are separate things, the bonus attack only does about 9 damage<sup>2</sup>, with 13 to hit. Much more balanced.

*I guess* not allowing this was a conscious decision by the game designers. Of course, now they have to make every racial natural attack an exception, but those do not cause balance issues with 1d4 or 1d6 damage.

### The exceptions are mentioned in the description

For example, the bite of Lizardfolk is a natural weapon (VGtM, p113):

> Your fanged maw is a natural weapon, which you can use to make unarmed strikes.

---

1. Mammoth form, 29 damage against prone enemies
2. 1d4+7 as Martial Arts