# Can a Beast Barbarian use the Unarmed Fighting fighting style with Claw attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, barbarian, unarmed-combat

If you have a Path of the Beast Barbarian who is using the Form of the Beast Claws, can this be combined with the Fighting Style: Unarmed Fighting to make the claws do 1d8 instead of 1d6 (if you are not wielding any weapons or shield)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can natural weapons be used for unarmed strikes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146884/can-natural-weapons-be-used-for-unarmed-strikes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, you cannot combine these effects.

Path of the Barbarian's Form of the Beast Claws states

> Each of your hands transforms into a claw, **which you can use as a weapon** if it’s empty.

Emphasis mine. So, the Barbarian's claws count as weapons specifically in this scenario. Unarmed fighting only turns into a D8:

> If you aren't wielding any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll

Therefore, you cannot gain any of the benefits from Unarmed Fighting when you have your claws out. You can either attack with your 1d6 claws twice, or take a different transformation and deal 1d8 unarmed once.

Answer (score 0):

Unarmed fighting style is not like monk maria arts.  Monk martial arts allows you to use monk martial arts for unarmed strikes (for  which the claw attacks would not quallify) and monk weapons (for which the claw attacks do qualify).

The claws are monk weapons because they are simple weapons for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).